# Margin messing up percentage based width

Tags: css

I have a `<ul>` inside of a `width: 100%;` container.

Each `<li>` has `width: 25%;`.

I want to have a `margin-left` on the `li` elements, but this screws up the width %.

Here is the fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/u3hTW/

To 'correct the issue, I can apply `box-sizing` to the `li` elements and use `padding` instead of `margin`, but the 'kicker' is that I want the `nth-child(1)` to have no `margin` or `padding` which causes it it to look different from the rest of the `li` elements.

Here is a fiddle showing that: http://jsfiddle.net/u3hTW/1/

I am wondering if there is a better way to be approaching this. The goal is to maintain a % based width, with space between all but the first child.

Comment: The box-sizing would only help you if you were using padding. The margin is ALWAYS added to the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a % for your width, and for your margins.

```
.list li {
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    margin-left: 2.66%;
}

.list li:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

[FIDDLE showing that approach](http://jsfiddle.net/pxp8p/)

In general to get spacing between containers I prefer margin, because later you may need inner padding for something else, or run into cross-browser box-sizing issues with padding.

Comment: This is what I will do. Thanks for the reply. What kind of cross browser box-sizing issues with padding have you run across? I am curious because I do the box-sizing and padding thing kind of often.

Comment: I had problems with it on a mobile site recently, but I now see that caniuse lists it as supported in most mobile browsers. We were testing that site on some game console browsers as well, so maybe it was just that. In which case, probably not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, you're already using your 100% by 4x25% width of each li element. So when you add the margin, the last one will 'jump', because < 25% of the container div remains.

What you can do is:

1. Make your li's a little smaller, like 23% or so, and use percentage for your margins. A little calculations is required to make sure everything is spaced apart evenly.
2. Use flexbox (please check if browsersupport meets your requirements)
   A compleet guide to this relatively new css boxmodel can be viewed here, as done by Chris Coyier: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula to calculate the width of the columns with the method suggested by cjspurgeon:

```
w = 100 - 2mc
    ---------
        c
```

Where:

w = width of the column

m = margin expressed in %

c = number of columns

The constant 100 = 100%, or total width of columns + margins.

The constant 2 is the two margins considered (left and right)

So, say you want 6 columns with a margin of 1.7% left and right:

```
w = (100 - 2(1.7 * 6)) / 6
```

w = 13.2666%

Your rule would look like this:

```
.column {
  width: 13.2666%;
  margin: 1.7%;
  float: left;
  /* whatever else is required */
}
```